# DateTime is giving unexpected result

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have tried this using Jodatime `DateTime`,

```
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime
            .parse("1-JAN-1900", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
            .plusSeconds(2075866000);
    String dateTimeStr = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(
            "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").print(dateTime);
    System.out.println(dateTimeStr);
```

I have also tried using Jodatime `MutableDateTime`

```
    MutableDateTime dateTime = MutableDateTime
            .parse("1-JAN-1900", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
    dateTime.add(DurationFieldType.seconds(), 2075866000);
    String dateTimeStr = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(
                "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").print(dateTime.toDateTime());
    System.out.println(dateTimeStr);
```

Both are giving me the same result, `1965/10/13 06:09:54`.

I expect, `1965/10/13 05:26:40`, instead. I'm getting this using Oracle query given below,

```
select to_date('1900-JAN-1') + 2075866000/86400 from dual
```

And upon contradiction between Joda and Oracle, I tried [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281900/01/01%2000:00:00%29%20%2b%202075866000%20seconds&dataset=), that is also giving me the same result as Oracle.

**Anyone please explain why is that difference?**

Comment: `2075866000/86400`, what is `86400` used for?

Comment: What is your default timezone? If it is in India, there are some weird adjustments in the 1930's that would affect the result.

Comment: I notice you're located in Malaysia - as Jim Garrison said, adjustments to that time zone in the last century may explain the discrepancy. See this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Malaysia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [timeanddate.com](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=122&syear=1925) there were timezone adjustments in Kuala Lumpur in 1901, 1905, 1933, 1941, 1942, 1945, the sum total of which probably explains the discrepancy you're seeing.

Edit: In fact, if you add up all the adjustments you get 43:14, which is exactly the discrepancy you're seeing.

JodaTime and Java are giving you the correct numbers.